# Spring Boot application delays passing request to controller in minutes

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm observing a weird effect: my spring-boot based REST service works perfectly but from time to time strange thing happens. 
I see in log the request is coming

```
07:20:53.330 DEBUGo.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter - Before request
```

But the first log inside the responsible controller is 20 minutes (!) later:

```
07:43:14.929 INFO c.l.controller.OrderController - >> ORDER::PATCH:
```

What are the possible explanations? Looks like API is half-frozen at the time. I see incoming requests but nothing is being processed.

UPDATE: Actually, I just learned that application continued only after the admin has pressed Ctrl+C in the console where he started the app before. How it can be explained?

Comment: Arnie can you describe the environment where your API is running (e.g. Tomcat, Linux, etc)?

Comment: It's just compiled .aar started on Windows, I suppose it has embedded tomcat, since no special configuration has been done.

Comment: Looks like the thread was blocked to serve the request. In this case, the client should get gateway timeout exception. How did you invoke the webservice (browser or postman) ?

Comment: Locally by curl (but I cannot reproduce it locally). In field this is customer application which sends HTTP requests, I have no idea with which technology they do it :/

Comment: But how would I figure out why my thread is blocked?

Comment: Colleagues, do I have a right understanding that without specific async configuration, Spring Boot will have only one receiving thread and if this one is blocked, the API basically stops, right?

Comment: Other sources say however, in default configuration, embedded Tomcat has 200 threads, but are those the receiving threads?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the question you need to answer:
Do you see a delay in processing of the messages?
If no,
then what you are seeing appears to be a delay in
flushing the log messages to the log.

If this is the case,
try sending 100 or 1000 requests to your server right after starting it.
This should be enough to cause the log cache to fill and get flushed to the file.